# Issue regarding the cast from a float matrix to a Java.Lang.Object using C# (Xamarin development environment)

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, casting, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to convert a multidimensional float matrix to a Java.Lang.Object in C#?
The neural network I use (.tflite format) is correctly loaded and to make inference two Java.Lang.Object are requested as Input parameters, hereafter InputObj01 and InputObj02:

1. InputObj01 --> Input to be classified. In my case Matrix Dimensions: [1, 4000, 2]
2. InputObj02 --> Output Model. In my case Matrix Dimension: [1, 4000]

I found no problems converting InputObj02 to Java.Lang.Object, using the following steps:

```
float[][] Input02 = new float[][]{ new float[4000] };  
var InputObj02 = Arrays.FromArray<float[]>(Input02);
```

But if I try to use the same technique to get InputObj01, in the following way:

```
float[][,] Input01 = new float[][,]{ new float[4000, 2] };
var InputObj01 = Arrays.FromArray<float[,]>(Input01)
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
**System.InvalidCastException:** 'Specified cast is not valid.'
```

Using directive:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;                                            
using System.IO;                                                
using Android.Content.Res;                                      
using Java.IO;                                                  
using Java.Nio.Channels;                                        
using Java.Nio;                                                 
using Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite;
using Java.Util;
```

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thanks for the reply, but this solution is not ideal in my situation. For other reasons, we have moved to native development and this exact problem has not been created in Android environment and iOS environment.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs, it may be easier to just use a simple loop:

```
        float[][,] Input01 = new float[][,] { new float[4000, 2] };
        List<float[,]> newList = new List<float[,]>();

        foreach (float[,] array in Input01)
        {
                newList.Add(array);
        }
```